# Не работают стили css в мобильной версии

Tags: css

Вопрос в следующем. Прописал стили для мобильной версии сайта. В режиме разработчика все показывается, как должно быть, на сторонних сервисах по просмотру адаптация сайта к телефону аналогично все правильно, а заходя на сайт через телефон показывает, как-будто ничего не прописано. В чем может быть проблема?

Если конкретнее, то не срабатывают стили при центрировании выпадающего списка, а именно значений, которое мы выбираем. Оно всегда показывается слева, хотя стили, чтобы выровнять по центру прописаны.

Прописано: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">.`

В режиме разработчика выглядит так: [image: В режиме разработчика]

Выглядит на телефоне: [image: Заходим с телефона]

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну и где код тогда?